# image loading on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, load, imageview

I'm trying to load an image to an imageview in an app made for iphone but is also supposed to have support to be run on ipad. so when i load an image in the iphone simulator, it works fine but when i switch to the ipad simulator the image doesn't load in the imageview. any suggestions??

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


//iPhone
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else {
//iPad

UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
UIPopoverController *popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];}


}
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: in iphone you present view and in ipad you use popover. So in (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
dont dismiss for ipad

Comment: - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    
    if
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }
    else {
        
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


    }
}
Like this?

Answer (score 0):

for iPad,

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    
    if
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }
    else {
        
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


    }
}

Comment: thsi will not work as the line you wrote is for presenting popover controller at certain position in ipad

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting sourceType in your Ipad coding
Add this line in your iPad coding

```
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
```

and also in delgate methods dismiss Popover as mention in comment

Comment: I'll answer my own question below in order to fit the new code. do you think that will work?

Comment: yes, but put your these line                                  self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];  above if statement

Comment: Still the same problem, the images loades when i try with the iphone simulator but not when i try with the ipad simulator

Comment: did your imageview connected in xib?

Comment: ofcourse.. it's weird because there is no errors in the debugger and it works flawlessly when tested in the iphone simulator. In the Ipad simulator it lets me choose a picture and instead of appearing in the imageview nothing happens. it just stays blank

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {


//iPhone
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else {
//iPad

UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
UIPopoverController *popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];}

}
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

if
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIPopoverController for presenting UIImagePicker in iPad.